# How to retrive data from ViewData in foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I have get records in ViewData["TutorList"] = GetData.Tables[0];

Here GetData DataSet and in that table[0] is bind with ViewData["TutorList"]

```
@foreach (var item in (DataTable)ViewData["TutorList"])
{
<tr>
<td>@item["Name"].ToString()</td>
</tr>
}
```

**How Can I get all the records in foreach**

Answer (score 2):

The following code should give you want you want

```
@foreach (DataRow item in ((DataTable)ViewData["TutorList"]).Rows)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item["Name"].ToString()</td>
    </tr>
}
```

But I would suggest that you use a view model specific to the view and use the associated Html helpers in your view.